# Mysterious data when summing numbers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I collected data using pandas, putting data, then summing each columns from 1 to 200 on 201 column and saved it as csv file.

But I think, it is something wrong.

[image]

From 1 to 200 columns, each columns have same number from top to bottom. But mysteriously, 201 column has different number on each line.

My question is the numbers on each columns from 1 to 200, are same but why the numbers on 201 columns different?

From 1 to 200, **every columns have to have different number** that I try to make, because the data was coded to update every minutes, which means the data on 201 column is only the data corrects.

You know, this is not asking about coding, but the number that shows me up.

Are there any one who experienced as same as with me ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your code with us.